# Execute raw query that could handle all numerous of documents mongo driver c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the situation that filtering condition on collection is quite long. And I prefer to write it by hand and using the mongoDb `RunCommandAsync` method in C# driver to get the Bson Document as result then Deserialize it back to object.

As the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/) said it will return a BsonDocument, instead of a Cursor to iterate with.

I made a small test from a collection with some dummy filter condition as below, and i got ~215k docs from robo 3T, but when it comes to `RunCommandAsync` in c#, it default return 101 document. I attempted to increase the `batchSize` to 200.000, but the execution can only return ~22k docs(which i guess it's the limitation of 4MB per batch operation).

```
var cmdDoc = @"{
'find': 'NotificationHistories',
'filter': {'CreatedTime': {$exists: true}}
'batchSize': 200000,
'singleBatch': true
}";
var cmd = new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>(cmdDoc);
var res = await database.RunCommandAsync(cmd, ReadPreference.PrimaryPreferred, CancellationToken.None);
```

So my final question is:

Is there anyway we can execute raw query that could handle all the numerous of documents ?
The result can be any of Cursor, BsonDocument, Array of BsonDocument,...

Or there's just no possible way to workaround this but use the normal `Find` or `Aggregate` method of Collection ?

Any clue would be appriciate, since i felt its quite long and cumbersome writing those especially with `Unwind`, `Group`, `Lookup`,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

101 records is a number of records in the firstBatch of your cursor, iterating of next records(batch by batch) should be done via [getMore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getMore/) command (but I think it's a wrong that you think in this way, I see no reason to avoid a regular way).

Comment: I successfully implement the code as you suggest, thanks mate.

But a tail question just across my mind, would the cursor auto destroy itself after when i iterate through it all ? (the cursor id turned back to 0 at this point)

Comment: Just a side note... I used regular way almost all the times, just doing raw query like this if I met some awkward cases.

Comment: >But a tail question just across my mind, would the cursor auto destroy itself after when i iterate through it all 
I think, the cursor will be auto destroyed when you received cursorId=0, but you can double check it with `killCursors` command https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/killCursors/ and analyzing `cursorsNotFound` field

Comment: Thanks again, successfully implement try catch in the case something weird happen, using `killCursors`. Good day mate :D